# Overriding resource from library in android app

Tags: android, android-resources

I started to use this library: https://github.com/MrBIMC/MaterialSeekBarPreference. When I use it I found that a slider is small. I found that it uses `msbp_seekbar_width` property:

```
   <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/msbp_seekbar_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

So I tried to override it in my app. I have nexus 5x, which shall be xxhdpi and 730 dpi wide: https://design.google.com/devices/. I put

```
<dimen name="msbp_seekbar_width">700dp</dimen>
```

value in `dimens.xml` in following qualifier directories: `values`, `w720dpi`, `xxhdpi`. But it had no effect. Is it possible to override a resource from a library?

Answer (score 1):

**Because that lib doesn't have dependency on your project**.. Try to extend used class from that lib ( if possible )  to your project and reuse again .. that would allow you to use resources from Lib and overrided resources in your project.
so SeekBar will be some thing like

```
<com.mycompany.myapp.widget.SeekBar
..
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/msbp_seekbar_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Addons:**
If that doesnt work.. you can copy the layout : R.layout.seekbar_view_layout to your project and be sure that you override the method where its used:

I dont know which one you are targeting .. so I list them all:

For SeekBarPreferenceView.java:

```
 @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.seekbar_view_layout, this);
        controllerDelegate.onBind(view);
    }
```

For SeekBarPreference.java:

```
private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.seekbar_view_layout);
        controllerDelegate = new PreferenceControllerDelegate(getContext(), false);

        controllerDelegate.setViewStateListener(this);
        controllerDelegate.setPersistValueListener(this);
        controllerDelegate.setChangeValueListener(this);

        controllerDelegate.loadValuesFromXml(attrs);
    }
```

For SeekBarPreferenceCompat.java:

```
 private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.seekbar_view_layout);
        controllerDelegate = new PreferenceControllerDelegate(getContext(), false);

        controllerDelegate.setViewStateListener(this);
        controllerDelegate.setPersistValueListener(this);
        controllerDelegate.setChangeValueListener(this);

        controllerDelegate.loadValuesFromXml(attrs);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that I shall create new class, let it derive from library's class, use new class and it suddenly starts to work?

Comment: No, it is the same. I have one occurence of my overriden preference and two original and they all look the same.